'Connection refused lost connection' error while using scp command
I tried to transfer a file from an HPC system to a remote system using the following command line:
scp /ANKAN/data/abc.pdf maslab-3@192.168.69.231:/data/ANKAN

But I am getting the following error:
ssh: connect to host 192.168.69.231 port 22: Connection refused 

lost connection

I tried all the commands given in the webpage https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-connection-refused, but nothing worked!
For your information, the port number of the HPC (from where I am transferring the files) is 4422. But when I gave the following command in the remote system:
sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config

the following lines are printed:
Port 22

#GatewayPorts no

So, I tried using the following command lines:
scp -P 4422 /ANKAN/data/abc.pdf maslab-3@192.168.69.231:/data/ANKAN

and
scp -P 22 /ANKAN/data/abc.pdf maslab-3@192.168.69.231:/data/ANKAN

But I am getting the same errors.
I asked the support team of that HPC system, and they informed us that the error was due to firewall restrictions. For some reason, the network is blocking data transfer from the remote system end.
For your information, to check if SSH is running in the remote host system or not, I gave the following command in the remote host system:
sudo systemctl status sshd

and the following lines are printed:
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-03-18 12:36:37 IST; 1 months 18 days ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 22317 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─22317 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

May 05 15:52:08 localhost.localdomain sshd[16995]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.68.8 port 56971 ssh2
May 05 15:52:08 localhost.localdomain sshd[17001]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.68.8 port 56972 ssh2
May 05 21:31:00 localhost.localdomain sshd[8533]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.68.8 port 55259 ssh2
May 05 21:31:01 localhost.localdomain sshd[8553]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.68.8 port 55261 ssh2
May 05 23:15:26 localhost.localdomain sshd[28161]: Address 192.168.69.231 maps to localhost.localdomain, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
May 05 23:15:31 localhost.localdomain sshd[28161]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.69.231 port 36212 ssh2
May 05 23:17:07 localhost.localdomain sshd[28951]: Address 192.168.69.231 maps to localhost.localdomain, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
May 05 23:17:10 localhost.localdomain sshd[28951]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.69.231 port 36214 ssh2
May 06 10:17:33 localhost.localdomain sshd[8965]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.68.8 port 60899 ssh2
May 06 10:17:33 localhost.localdomain sshd[8973]: Accepted password for maslab-3 from 192.168.68.8 port 60901 ssh2

I want to mention that when I am using WinSCP tool, I am able to transfer the files from the HPC to my Windows system. But speed is very slow. But when I tried to transfer the files from the HPC to the Linux system, the scp command was not working, and I am getting the above error.
I can't figure out what is going wrong here. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?
Also, I want to know if the speed of the file transfer using WinSCP in Windows and scp in Linux is the same or not. I am looking forward to getting a positive response.

The /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the HPC where you are transferring files from should not be involved here - it's the server config on the remote host 192.168.69.231 that determines what port you should specify in the scp command. Is there even an SSH server running on 192.168.69.231?

I gave the command 'sudo grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config' in the remote host system. So, do I have to give 'scp -P 22' to transfer the files from the HPC to the remote host system. I have also edited my question to answer your question regarding the SSH server running on the remote host system since there is not much of scope to give the information in the comments. I hope it will help you to understand more about my problem. I am really looking forward to getting any help from you.
